# Html/CSS Upload File

Tags: html, css

this is upload file code:

```
<form>
<input type="file" name="file"/>
</form>
```

It's appear a text box and BROWSE button to upload a file.

Well, But is there any way to upload a file by just click on "some" text, Example: "Upload your file" text. After click on this text then upload box will appear.

Comment: yes this is possible apply some css on the input tag and you are done

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Directly you can't set any css on input type file you need to use trick for this. see this [plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/filestyle)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/RffbE/

```
<form>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="display:none"/>
<span onclick="doTrick()">Upload your file</span>
</form>
```

and use this javascript function.

```
function doTrick() {
    document.getElementById('file').click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need this

Please see my jsfiddle

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ks5r7/6/

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function show()
            {
                document.getElementById('box').style.display='inline';
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="show"><a href="#" onclick="show()">Upload my file</div>

        <div id="box" style="display:none";><input type="file"/></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can style each element here